# Pandas reshape a multicolumn dataframe long to wide with conditional check

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a `pandas` data frame as follows:

```py
id     group    type    action    cost
101    A        1                 10
101    A        1       repair    3
102    B        1                 5
102    B        1       repair    7
102    B        1       grease    2
102    B        1       inflate   1
103    A        2                 12
104    B        2                 9
```

I need to reshape it from long to wide, but depending on the value of the `action` column, as follows:

```py
id     group    type    action_std    action_extra
101    A        1       10            3
102    B        1       5             10
103    A        2       12            0
104    B        2       9             0
```

In other words, for the rows with empty `action` field the `cost` value should be put under the `action_std` column, while for the rows with non-empty `action` field the `cost` value should be summarized under the `action_extra` column.

I've attempted with several combinations of `groupby` / `agg` / `pivot` but I cannot find any fully working solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you simply split the `cost` column into a `cost`, and a `cost_extra` column. Something like the following:

```py
import numpy as np

result = df.assign(
    cost_extra=lambda df: np.where(
        df['action'].notnull(), df['cost'], np.nan
    )
).assign(
    cost=lambda df: np.where(
        df['action'].isnull(), df['cost'], np.nan
    )
).groupby(
    ["id", "group", "type"]
)["cost", "cost_extra"].agg(
    "sum"
)
```

`result` looks like:

```
                cost  cost_extra
id  group type                  
101 A     1     10.0         3.0
102 B     1      5.0        10.0
103 A     2     12.0         0.0
104 B     2      9.0         0.0
```

Comment: You can [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) two columns at once with comma separation.

Answer (score 1):

Check `groupby` with `unstack`

```
df.cost.groupby([df.id,df.group,df.type,df.action.eq('')]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
action          False  True 
id  group type              
101 A     1         3     10
102 B     1        10      5
103 A     2         0     12
104 B     2         0      9
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hints, this is the solution that I finally like the most (also for its simplicity):

```py
df["action_std"] = df["cost"].where(df["action"] == "")
df["action_extra"] = df["cost"].where(df["action"] != "")
df = df.groupby(["id", "group", "type"])["action_std", "action_extra"].sum().reset_index()
```